ModuleNotFoundError: No module named - Python packages
I'm trying to get a handle on using modules and packages in Python when dealing with different directories. Here’s what my project structure looks like, with empty init files:
├── Dockerfile
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── fct.py
└── config
    ├── __init__.py
    └── settings.py


In fct.py, I have this line: from config.settings import sum_fct And my Dockerfile looks like this:
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /application 
COPY . .
CMD ["python", "app/fct.py"]

But when I run my container, I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app/fct.py", line 1, in <module>
    from config.settings import sum_fat
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'

Can anyone help me understand what I'm missing here?
I don’t want to use PYTHONPATH as an environment variable or mess with sys
Thanks in advance!

Just package your library and install it locally

Your title says "python packages" and yet there is nothing in your setup to make your code a package. You need a pyproject.toml file (or in older versions of python, a setup.py file)

When you run python and specify a script in a different directory (as you did here with python app/fct.py), that directory is treated as the default module path.  So you are already inside of the app directory, and thus config is not found.
